# How can I tell when an array element has been .popped()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of making a card game using jQuery and JavaScript. I have an array that I am using `.pop()` connected to a `.click` function to replicate the user removing and displaying a card from a deck one at a time. The real game has cards that are only added to the deck if another card is pulled first. My plan for handling this originally was to create an if function seen below.

HTML:

```
<p id="cards">click anywhere on screen to flip a card. Enjoy!</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#gameBoard").click(function () { 
    $('#cards').html(newCardArray.pop());   
    if ($('#cards').val("some card value") {
        newCardArray.push("dependent card value");
    }
});
```

This worked for pushing "dependent card value" to the array but it was added immediately on page load not after the "some Card Value" was printed to the P tag like I wanted. I assumed this is because there's a variable in front of what I've Pseudo coded as "some card value" hence I decided to use `includes()` because the string will never say "some card Value" It will be more like var + "some card value". Anyway my second attempt is as follows.

HTML:

```
<p id="cards">click anywhere on screen to flip a card. Enjoy!</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#gameBoard").click(function () {
    $('#cards').html(newCardArray.pop());   
    var cardValue = document.getElement.ById("cards").textContent;
    var n = str.includes("some card value");
    if (n = true) {
        newCardArray.push("dependent card value");
    }
});
```

This didn't work either. It never pushes the value to the array and after I've cycled through all the cards in the array the click function does nothing. In the actual code I have a function for ending the game when the array is empty and that doesn't trigger so I'm assuming the `includes()` line is the problem.

Comment: `if ($('#cards').val("some card value")` won't work. First, you're missing a `)`. Second, `.val("some card value")` doesn't test the value, it changes the value. And only inputs have values.

Comment: In `if (n = true)`, `=` is assignment, you need to use `==` or `===` to compare. But you can just write `if (n)`

Answer (score 0):

Put the result of popping in a variable so you can use it for other things.

```
$("#gameBoard").click(function () { 
    var card = newCardArray.pop();
    $('#cards').html(card);   
    if (card == "some card value") {
        newCardArray.push("dependent card value");
    }
});
```